# If $f\in L^1$ then is $g(x)=\int_x^{x+1} f(t)dt$ is in $C_0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Original question is that for $1\le p<\infty$ if $f\in L^p$, and $g(x)=\int_x^{x+1}f(t)dt$ then, $g\in C_0$.
I can prove for the case $1<p<\infty$ don't know how to for $p=1$.
How can I prove it?

Comment: What is $C_0$ ?

Comment: @Mher $C_0$ is the set of continuous functions decaying at infinity.

Comment: If $f_n=f\cdot\chi_{[-n,n]}$, it follows from Dominated Convergence that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L_1$. It then follows that $h(x)=\int_x^\infty |f|\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. You have $g(x)=h(x+1)-h(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, make that $h_n=\int_x^\infty f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral of a function in $L^1$ is absolutely continuous: for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ with the property that $|\int_E f(t) \, dt| < \epsilon$ whenever $|E| < \delta$.

Try to show that if $|x-y| < \delta/2$, then $g(x) - g(y)$ equals the integral of $f$ over a set with measure less than $\delta$.

---

To show that $f$ vanishes at $\infty$ define (per David Mitra's comment) $f_n(x) = f(x) \chi_{[-n,n]}(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Then $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$ and $|f_n| \le |f|$. By LDCT, $\int |f - f_n| \to 0$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $n$ so that $\int |f - f_n| < \epsilon$. If $x > n$ then
$$ |g(x)| \le \int_{x}^{x+1} |f|  \le \int_x^{x+1} |f_n| + \int_x^{x+1} |f - f_n| < \epsilon$$ because $t \in [x,x+1]$ implies $f_n(t) = 0$. This proves that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $n$ such that  $$x > n \implies |g(x)| < \epsilon.$$ This is what $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$ means. The proof of the limit at $-\infty$ is very similar.

Comment: Yeah I figure out how to show that it is Continuous. But what about vanishing at infinity?

Comment: See David Mitra's comment above. LDCT does the job nicely.

Comment: Could you help me more? I can't see any connecion between $||f_n-f||_1\rightarrow 0$ and $h(x)=\int_x^\infty|f|\rightarrow0$.